# Query specific ~/.Xresources value

Tags: x11, xrdb

I would like to query a single value from ~/.Xresources. `xrdb -query` gives me the whole configuration, but I would specifically like to echo the *value* of an *individual* property (e.g., `URxvt.internalBorder` or `*color14`). How can I do this?

Comment: You could just grep from what you want, for example: `xrdb -query | grep URxvt.internalBorder`

Comment: And if the solution with `grep` (IMHO the simplest one) is not acceptable: It's possible to do this using the X API, but you'll have to write your own program for it, e.g. in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `grep` and `cut` to parse the output of `xrdb -query`:

`xrdb -query | grep "URxvt.internalBorder" | cut -f 2`

returns `30`. Another example:

`xrdb -query | grep "*color14" | cut -f 2`

returns `#d65d0e`.

Translation:

- `xrdb -query` outputs the current `~/.Xresources` properties
- `grep "foo.bar"` gets the line on which a specific property is defined
- `cut -f 2` gets the second "field", excluding the first property